# vertical divider using css ( ie. issue )

Tags: css, internet-explorer

We are using vertical dividers using css.

Code is:

```
.sectiondivider {
 border-left:1px solid #d9dbdd; 
 border-right:1px solid #ffffff; 
 height:300px;
 position:absolute;
 right:500px;
 top:310px; 
}

.section2divider {
 border-left:1px solid #d9dbdd; 
 border-right:1px solid #ffffff; 
 height:300px;
 position:absolute;
 left:720px;
 top:310px; 
}
```

Problem is they are not being rendered in correct position in internet explorer. Is there a better way to overcome this issue.
Tested in
FF
Chrome
IE 8

Comment: I wish IE were more cooperative.

Comment: which IE is giving you problem.  You said tested on IE 8, does that mean it works well on IE 8 or do you mean having problems on IE 8.

Comment: How about a link or the HTML? Both selectors are using absolute positioning so they are affected by the parent container. The problem could be which parent has the positioning set.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion for trying:

earlier version of IE had issue with `right` in CSS.  Try to see if you can use `left` to do it instead and try it again in IE.

Comment: Yeah tried left , made no difference. Would be nice to be able to add to css... <if IE ignore previous style and put the bloody thing here instead >